# Supervisor configuration does not work on my server

Tags: centos7, supervisord

I am trying to run the command below in the background using `supervisord`:

```
php /home/instacheeta/artisan queue:work --timeout=120
```

After installing the supervisor service on my server, defining its configuration and starting that, there is no change on the database to indicate supervisor is running the PHP application.

My supervisor configuration:

```
[program:instacheeta]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s
command=php /home/instacheeta/artisan queue:work --timeout=120
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/instacheeta/worker.log
```

`queue:work` fires after running `cronjob` each minute and works until finish.

`cronjob` works fine; I checked that on my database to verify new data is stored every minute. Unfortunately, supervisor does not seem to run the defined command.

I don't get any error on `worker.log`. Other information for troubleshooting:

```
[root@host instacheeta]# ps aux|grep supervisor
root      3267  0.0  0.2 219784 12992 ?        Ss   11:47   0:02 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord
root     18279  0.0  0.0 112680   948 pts/0    S+   14:38   0:00 grep --color=auto supervisor
```

Fail to adding program to `supervisorctl`:

```
[root@host instacheeta]# supervisorctl add instacheeta
ERROR: no such process/group: instacheeta
```

supervisor status:

```
[root@host instacheeta]# supervisorctl status
[root@host instacheeta]#
```

Comment: Have you reloaded the supervisor configuration? I ask because your `ps` output shows `supervisor` as starting at 11:47, while your `grep` command ran at 14:38. Either restart the supervisor service, or type `supervisorctl reread` to update the configuration. If you have restarted supervisor, do you see any output in its log file to indicate an error reading your configuration file?

Comment: @CosmicOssifrage after reread supervisor and `supervisorctl restart all` i get this result:  `cheeta:cheeta_0: stopped   cheeta:cheeta_0: started`, but i think supervisor dont work

Comment: Your program is defined with the name `instacheeta` in the configuration file. Is there another program called `cheeta`? What does `supervisorctl status` say?

Comment: @CosmicOssifrage i change program name to `cheeta` and i add that to supervisor, output of `status` is `cheeta:cheeta_0                  RUNNING   pid 22526, uptime 0:02:52` but command don't run inside that to run my jobs

Comment: It looks like your process is running then. One observation to note: your program will not be invoked periodically, like a `cron`. It will run as a single process repeatedly. You will need to provide some wrapping logic if you require repeated invocation to do some work.

Comment: @CosmicOssifrage i'm not sure to can that, because i dont have more information about that, could you config that with `anydesk`? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supervisor configuration needs to be reloaded.

There are two methods for this, either:

1. Restart the `supervisor` service using the `service` tool (`service supervisor restart`). This would call all supervised processes, but as you currently have no such processes running, this is not an issue.
2. Ask the `supervisor` daemon to dynamically reload its configuration from the configuration files. Run `supervisorctl reread` followed by `supervisorctl update` to update the configuration. You can now use `start` to start the program, or `status` to view its status.

---

## `supervisor` is not `cron`!

In your question, you state:

> `cronjob` works fine; I checked that on my database to verify new data is stored every minute. Unfortunately, supervisor does not seem to run the defined command.

Do be aware that if you formerly had a cronjob which invoked the command on a regular cycle, `supervisor` will not do this without external intervention or unless the program dies after it finishes working. supervisor is typically intended to invoke binaries provide a service and stay running once started.

I would recommend changing the application so it starts once and has an internal schedule on which it does whatever database actions required.

Comment: by `cronjob` i create new job and queue on my web application that stored them into database and with `supervisor` i'm trying to run this jobs in background, command of this action is `php /home/instacheeta/artisan queue:work --timeout=120` which should be run in background

Comment: @DolDurma I made a chatroom here for us to discuss. Please join me! https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82682/discussion-between-doldurma-and-cosmic-ossifrage